# Google map api billing

Tags: html, google-maps, web-services, google-maps-api-3

I need to include google map in my website for assignment purpose. But the google developer site asked me to key in my credit card info in order to get the API Key. Are they going to charge me monthly? It's not for commercial purposes. Just for the assignment project. Please help :( Thank you :)

Comment: What about reading the documentation on billing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enable your billing account, you will be entitled for a one time free $300 credit (usable for Google Cloud Platform Products including Google Maps Platform) and a monthly recurring free $200 credit (exclusive use for Google Maps Platform), In case you  consume all of the free credits, you will receive an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error and will not be billed unless you upgrade your billing account.

So you won't be charged for additional fees if you just enable your billing account.

You may also Cap your usage to make sure you will not go more than the free credits, you may visit this [link](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage) to learn more.

Comment: I thought Google would charge me without any warning once I submitted my card details. Now I know how it works.Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: You're Welcome! :)